# Strange bug - Google Action is swapping voice mid-interaction

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, ssml

We are using Female 1 as the voice in our Google Action. Our intent is fulfilled by a cloud function, that responds with some SSML.

After triggering the intent a several times, the speaker emits a low pitched earcon, and swaps the voice to Male.

Has anyone experienced this or know what's happening?

Comment: This happens on Google Home and the Lenovo Smart Display. Voice "randomly" changes to male for one question, then changes back.

Comment: We've had similar problems, and as I remember one was just like this. I can't remember the exact issue, but it was something to do with a  specific `<break>` command. Can you reproduce the issue in the [online version](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) with the same voice and SSML?